# Pi 3 does not boot

Tags: raspbian, boot, hdmi, video

I just got my Raspberry Pi 3, put the content of the NOOBS folder onto the sd card and connected it to my TV via HDMI, but do not get any output.
One LED stays red at all times.

I read that this means, that there are problems with the power supply, is that true? I already tried two plugs and three different cables.

Another thing i tried is changing the config.txt with this:

```
config_hdmi_boost=4
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_drive=2
```

Is it correct that the config.txt is inside /os/Raspbian/boot.tar.xz? Do i just unzip this file and then edit the boot/config.txt file?

Edit: I just read [here](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Red_power_LED_is_on.2C_green_LED_does_not_flash.2C_nothing_on_display) that the pi does not boot. What could be the problem? I just copied the content of the noobs folder

Edit2: Somehow my Pi did not boot with Raspbian. I put Ubuntu Mate on it and it is working now.

Comment: What is the output of the power supply plugs? How are they labled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the NOOBs Installer somehow did not work for my Pi, i installed Ubuntu Mate and it booted correctly.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the red led just means that electricity is reaching the board. **No reason to panic.**

Because I couldn't use the NOOBs setup either, I strongly recommend you try to install the image of your favourite operating system directly on the sd card.

---

**Useful links:**

Raspbian img file:
http://www.chip.de/downloads/Raspbian-Jessie-fuer-Raspberry-Pi_56691903.html

Img installer:
http://www.chip.de/downloads/Win32-Disk-Imager_46121030.html

---

*Also, make sure the card is formared and has at least the speed level 10.*

Answer (score 1):

I experienced similar difficulties in getting my new Pi 3 to boot. I eventually got it working after solving the following two problems:

- I had absent-mindedly formatted the SD Card as NTFS, instead of FAT32 (NOOBs requires FAT32).
- The power supply (an old 700A phone charger I used for my Model A Pi) was too small. I'd recommend a 2A supply, because I was still getting the low power warning with a 1.5A supply.

Hope this helps.